# Can't get Dictionary<> (Or ObservableCollection<KVP>) to bind to ListView

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to get a Dictionary to bind to a ListView.  Having not worked, I changed the Datatype to ObservableCollection> but still no joy.  I know I'm missing something silly but....

The data is readonly, meaning that the UI will not update it, only the code behind.

The XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">  

        <ListView Grid.Column="1" Background="Orange" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Item" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

The DataObject:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> MyItems{ get; set; }
```

And the assignment:

```
this.MyItems = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(
            PIData.GetNeededItems(itemName));
```

Comment: Make sure that your Window inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged` and apply an `OnPropertyChanged()` call to your property, otherwise it will not update the UI. You may also change the mode of your `ItemsSource` binding to `OneWay`, to ensure your collection cannot be modified from the UI.

Comment: @kw1jybo when do you set `MyItems`?

Comment: Alternatively to implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, assign MyItems before InitializeComponent is called. Explicitly setting the Binding Mode to OneWay is pointless, as that is the default here anyway.

Comment: MyItems is assigned after some processing when the user clicks on another control, so cannot assign them before InitializeComponent is called as the data will change during runtime.

Comment: As a note, if you do not later add or remove items, it isn't necessary to use ObservableCollection. A simple Dictionary would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the MyItems property before InitializeComponent is called.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    MyItems = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(
        PIData.GetNeededItems(itemName));

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

If that is not possible, implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> myItems;

    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> MyItems
    {
        get { return myItems; }
        set
        {
            myItems = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyItems)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Had the INotifyPropertyChanged, but missed the Invoke on the PropertyChanged.